# Ionic 2 Side Menu Not Popping Up

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am completely new to Ionic as of last night and I've created a blank project and now stupidly realized that I'd like to have a side menu in there. So I've followed a couple of online tutorials to add one in, but no matter what I try I can get the menu to show when I click the menu toggle icon button.

Here's what I've added in to try and make this work:

app.html

```
<ion-menu side="right" [content]="content">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button>Page 1</button>
            <button>Page 2</button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #content [root]="rootPage" swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

home-logged-in.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color='primary'>
    <button ion-button menu-toggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong attribute. Replace:

```
<button ion-button menu-toggle>
```

With:

```
<button ion-button menuToggle>
```